# "Undersize" as an adjective? Where did the "d" go?

Tags: adjectives

As I was reading [this article](http://grantland.com/features/nba-golden-state-warriors-draymond-green-michigan-state-spartans/), I came across the word "undersize" being used three separate times as an adjective. I was confused, as I don't think I've ever seen that word used that way before (or at all). A couple of days later, I read [*another* article](http://grantland.com/the-triangle/the-nbanfl-crossover-who-is-the-aaron-rodgers-of-basketball/) written by a different author that used the same word in the same capacity. What gives? Why not just use "undersized"? Is "undersize" even an actual adjective?

Comment: The final /d/ been reduced, which is the fate of predictable final stops, especially before words beginning with consonants, which is almost all words. So _undersized fish_ contains an internal /df/ cluster (spaces between words exist only in writing, not in speech), which is very hard to pronounce, and gets simplified instantly to /f/, producing _undersize fish_, which is what people hear, and theforefore write. Yes, it is an actual adjective, and a noun, and a verb. In the right circumstances.

Comment: It drives me crazy too, sometimes, but it seems to be inevitable. "Iced tea" is hanging on by the skin of its teeth.

Comment: @JohnLawler "He is undersize" is written in the first article without any words after it, so what would be the reasoning for that? Might it be just for consistency's sake?

Comment: He's not oversize, he's not normal size, he's  undersize. What's the problem here?

Comment: I suppose nothing, but oversize/undersize just seem off to me, and I would use "normal-sized" over "normal size" every time.

Comment: @JohnLawler. Is this about phonetics or about morphology? I do not think "the final /d/ has been reduced"; "undersize" is a compound of the same type as "kingsize".

Comment: For some people, that is undoubtedly true. For others, not. We all hear what we (think we) hear, and we all parse accordingly. The amazing thing is that we can sometimes understand one another, which is a tribute to the evolutionary design of real (i.e, spoken) language, the ultimate irrelevance of syntax, and the importance of having a human mind in circuit.

Answer (score 2):

According to [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/undersized?q=undersize), both `undersized` and `undersize` are used. Same for [oversized/oversize](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oversized?q=oversize)

It's not that unusual to use `undersize` if you think about it. We don't think of similar adjectives like `overweight` to be weird.

Comment: This is genref; correctly answering 'Where did the _d_ go?' would make it an acceptable answer.